# GroupBy query is slow what are the other options?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I need a query to select rows with minimum Insert Date Time. but groupby query is very slow

what can I do instead of groupby?

How can improve the performance of the query?

Is there any other way to write this query using linq?

Number of rows in my table is around **600,000** rows and growing

fullsimnumber isn't **indexed** but isdeleted and insertdatetime are **indexed**.

fullsimnumber is a column which consist of three **indexed** coloumn prec+cod+subscribec.

my problem is with linq queries which always gives **timeout** exception.

I changed fullsimnumber to groupby prec,cod,subscribec which are indexed but still getting tiemout exception

Im using linq to EF, (code first style) and my query in sql is:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Sim AS t1
    JOIN (SELECT FullSimNumber,MIN(InsertDateTime) AS insd
          FROM dbo.Sim 
          GROUP BY FullSimNumber) AS t2
    ON t1.FullSimNumber = t2.FullSimNumber AND t1.InsertDateTime = t2.insd
WHERE t1.IsDeleted = 0
```

and my query in linq

```
from s in ADbContext.Numbers
where !s.IsDeleted
group s by s.FullSimNumber
into g
let sd = g.OrderBy(x => x.InsertDateTime).FirstOrDefault()
select sd;
```

Comment: What are your indexes on the table?

Comment: You could try it with a `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FullSImNumber ORDER BY InsertDateTime)` in a subselect maybe? Don't know if that will be faster though, it depends on the indexes used..

Comment: Query plan please. Also I would say the problem starts with a bad data structure that requires that subquery. And goes on with totally not good enough hardware.

Comment: question updated with specifying indexed coulomns.

Answer (score 1):

without any data on indexes and amounts of rows and such it is hard to know what exactly is needed to make your query faster. One thing which is worthwhile to try out is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Sim AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 FullSimNumber
        , InsertDateTime AS insd
    FROM dbo.Sim t2
    WHERE t1.FullSimNumber = t2.FullSimNumber
        AND t1.InsertDateTime = t2.insd
    ORDER BY InsertDateTime DESC
    ) AS t2
WHERE t1.IsDeleted = 0
```

Again this could very well be worse! test it and compare the execution times and load.

Comment: This won't work as you're mentioning alias `t2` before declaring it :) I think you need to alias `dbo.Sim` in the subquery

Comment: How do i do it in linq ef?